# Is there a better way to count punctuation in a sentence?

Tags: python, counting, punctuation

I want to count 'end sentences' e.g. full stops, exclamation marks, and question marks.

I have written a little loop to do this, but I was wondering if there is a better way. Not allowed to use built-in functions.

```
for line in textContent:
    numberOfFullStops += line.count(".")
    numberOfQuestionMarks += line.count("?")
    numberOfQuestionMarks += line.count("!")

numberOfSentences = numberOfFullStops + numberOfQuestionMarks + numberOfExclamationMarks
```

Comment: Do you need separate counts for them? What's the purpose here - to count the punctuation or to count the number of sentences? "Because this is not 5 sentences!!!!!"

Comment: What counts as a "built in function" here? Can you use standard library modules?

Comment: sorry. I meant methods. As an example, if there is something which could strip it automatically then we are not allowed to use it e.g if we were sorting we are not allowed to use variable.sort()

Comment: But you're allowed to use `.count`?

Comment: @JonClements I need to see how many sentences have been found.

Comment: How many sentences is this!!!!!!!!!!?

Comment: @JonClements using .count was the only way i could think of. Complete beginner here.

Comment: @JonClements not many sentences. Could be a max of 20. Not specified really.

Comment: Not to offend asker or anyone. (1) write a for loop to count character is basic, and doesn't use `.count()`; (2) we don't do homework for no good evidence of your effort.

Comment: and @JonClements is right that counting punt is not the correct way to solve your problem either.

Comment: Who ever said this was homework?

Comment: A suggestion, include in your question a sample input and excepted output.  Example `"Here is a sentence. It has some exclamations!!" --> {".": 1, "!": 2}`.  Also see `collections.Counter` and `string.punctutation`.

Comment: I think @JonClements is pointing out that the name `numberOfSentences` seems incorrect.  You must mean `numberOfPunctuations`, correct?

Comment: Ok I see what you say saying however I created a variable called textCount which would let someone enter text. This would then calculate how many sentences was in the text. We can end sentences using . Or ? Or !    My logic was to count how many of these are in the string.

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming you want to count terminal punctuation in one sentence*, we can produce a dictionary of (character, count) pairs by looping over the characters of each string and filtering the punctuations.

**Demo**

Here are three options presented top-down with intermediate- to beginner-level data structures:

```
import collections as ct


sentence = "Here is a sentence, and it has some exclamations!!"
terminals = ".?!"

# Option 1 - Counter and Dictionary Comprehension
cd = {c:val for c, val in ct.Counter(sentence).items() if c in terminals}
cd
# Out: {'!': 2}


# Option 2 - Default Dictionary
dd = ct.defaultdict(int)
for c in sentence:
    if c in terminals:
        dd[c] += 1
dd
# Out: defaultdict(int, {'!': 2})


# Option 3 - Regular Dictionary
d = {}
for c in sentence:
    if c in terminals:
        if c not in d:
            d[c] = 0
        d[c] += 1
d
# Out: {'!': 2}
```

To extend further, for a list of separate `sentences`, loop around one of the latter options.

```
for sentence in sentences:
    # add option here
```

Note: to sum the total punctuations per sentence, total the `dict.values()`, e.g. `sum(cd.values())`.

---

**Update**: *assuming you want to split a sentence by terminal punctutation*, use regular expressions:

```
import re


line = "Here is a string of sentences.  How do we split them up?  Try regular expressions!!!"


# Option - Regular Expression and List Comprehension
pattern = r"[.?!]"
sentences = [sentence for sentence in re.split(pattern, line) if sentence]
sentences
# Out: ['Here is a string of sentences', '  How do we split them up', '  Try regular expressions']

len(sentences)
# Out: 3
```

Notice `line` has 5 terminals, but only 3 sentences.  Thus regex is a more reliable approach.

**References**

- [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)
- [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples)
- [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split)
- [List comprehension](http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/)

Comment: Thank you for this. :-)  Big help.

Comment: No problem.  I've updated the post based on your comments, hopefully closer to what you are looking for. Also, as answers continue to be posted, don't forget to upvote ones you find helpful and accept a final solution.